# Elasticsearch Boolean query with Constant score wrapper

Tags: elasticsearch

When using elasticsearch-7 I'm confused by es compound queries syntax.

Though reading es documents repeatedly but i just find standard syntax of Boolean or Constant score seperately.

As it illuminate，i understand what is 'query context' and what is 'filter context'.But when combining these two query type in a single query i don't know what it mean.

Let's see a example:

```
GET /classes_test/_search
{
  "size": "21",
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "class_name": "29386556"
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "master": "7033560"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "assistant": "7033560"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "students": "7033560"
              }
            }
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": 1,
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "class_id": 0
              }
            }
          ],
          "filter": [
            {
              "term": {
                "class_status": "1"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query can be executed and response well.Each item in response content has a '_score' value with 1.0.

So,is it mean that the sub bool query as a entirety is in a filter context though it has a 'must' and 'should'?

Also i found boolean query can have a constant score sub query.

Why es allow these syntax but has no more words to explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `constant_score` query, you'll never get scores different than 1.0, unless you specify `boost` parameters in which case the score will match those.

If you need scoring you obviously need to ditch `constant_score`.

In your case, your `match` query on `class_name` cannot yield any other score than 1 or 0 since this is basically a yes/no filter, not a matching based on full-text search.

To sum up, all your query executes in a filter context (hence score 0 or 1) since you don't rely on full-text search. So you get scoring whenever you use full-text search, not because you use a `match` query. In your case, you can merge all `must` constraints into `filter`, it won't make any difference since you only have filters (yes/no matches) and no full-text search.

Comment: So you mean "match" do what it should do as usual but just jump over scoring.In other words "filter" in constant score query would cause all query in it working without scoring.Without scoring,the response will be returned faster than usual boolean query.Is it right as i understand?

Comment: `match` alone doesn't bump scoring. In order to get scoring you need two things: 1) run a full-text search (i.e. `match`) on a `text` field (not `keyword` or numeric) 2) wrapped inside a `bool/must/should` query.

Comment: What you said make me confused again.Excuse me.Just use the example in the post.If the `class_name` is a text field,dose the `match` bump scoring or not?

Comment: It's not a full text search, it's an exact search. You're simply trying to find documents which have `class_name: 29386556`, there's no full-text search involved, it's just a filter. Putting that match clause inside a `must` won't imply scoring, it's just a yes/no filter. Full-text search is "find documents whose title matches `The quick brown dog`", you're going to find many documents which have similar titles, and can be scored by similarity. It's different than a yes/no exact match.

Comment: Maybe I give a bad example.What about this: 

```
"query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "class_name": "a good boy"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now it's a full text search. Does the `match` find documents that match "a good boy" with scoring or not? What i mean "scoring" involves a serial action es do to caculate the score.

Comment: no because of the [`constant_score` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html), it's not meant for scoring, it will always return... a constant score equal to the boost of the query (default 1). If you remove `constant_score/filter` and simply use the `bool` query, then you'll get proper scoring. It's very easy to try it out actually, just run the different queries, and you'll see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203468/discussion-between-poettian-and-val).